# Rights Granted by ALTER RESOURCES Permission

Tags: sql-server, security

In SQL Server (2016 and greater), what rights does the **ALTER RESOURCES** server permission control?

Comment: If I'd had to guess, I'd say it's the resource governor commands, even though those document that you need `CONTROL SERVER`. Or possibly that was the intent, but it's not implemented (yet); I haven't tested. There is no command where it's documented that `ALTER RESOURCES` permission is needed, at least.

Comment: I'd thought the same thing and found the same thing (through BoL). I created a new login, granted it control server, denied alter resources, and then went to work altering things. I didn't get stopped on anything I tried. So annoyed this isn't better documented.

Comment: `ALTER RESOURCES` was introduced in SQL Server 2012, and so were major enhancements to the resource governor -- this seems too close to be coincidental. My money is definitely on a vestigial permission that was *intended* to give you more granular control over the resource governor, but was not implemented either due to time constraints or because of the limited value -- if you think about it, it makes little sense to have a scenario where an account has `CONTROL SERVER` and not `ALTER RESOURCES`, and vice versa -- resource pools are all about controlling the server.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - `ALTER ANY RESOURCES` existed before that and seems to be the same thing. ["Grants or denies the ability to manage disk resources for SQL Server."](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1714/server-level-permissions-for-sql-server-2005-and-sql-server-2008/)

Comment: What commands do we think "disk resources" comprises? And, thank you by the way!

Comment: same as diskadmin here I imagine https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1887/understanding-sql-server-fixed-server-roles/

Comment: @MartinSmith: that's weird, since `ALTER ANY RESOURCES` seems fairly obscure and little used -- why introduce a synonym for that? But since `ALTER ANY RESOURCES` is now [no longer present on the overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-server-permissions-transact-sql), this may very well be the world's least important grammar fix! (I guess I was wrong about those time constraints...)